# textbox onblur prevents any further events from firing

Tags: javascript

I have textbox for email id. On blur of this textbox I am checking if this email id is already present in the database or not using ajax call.
If email is already present in the database then contents are cleared from this textbox and focus is set.

I also have a checkbox which copies content of few fields along with the textbox for email to another set of fields.

At present when focus is in text box for email id and if checkbox clicked using mouse only on blur event is fired and checkbox doesn't changes its state.

As a user experience one expects checkbox to be checked on unchecked if it is clicked. Currently this doesn't happen.

Is there a way to fire another event after onblur is complete?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Can you please update in fiddle.

Comment: The code in the fiddle works with simple innerHTML set to label but I have an ajax call in my code. Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Saurabhd12/vtmg9ou7/